# why are not offline html 5 video/audio player making the news?

Tags: html, audio, video, offline

I m really excited to know that html 5 has in build support for audio and video playback( I know its old news but I just woke up ! :P) . What is even more exciting is that it can play local audio/video files in matters of some click. I had a look at this [offline audio player](http://antimatter15.github.com/player/player.html) , could not find any offline video player.

my question is why is that people are not developing an offline media player which could just be loaded form a website ? are there some issues ? Thanks

Comment: First of all, wrong site for this question. Secondly, don't get too excited, the HTML5 Video API still has ALOT of shortcomings and a LONG way to go before it will really be viable. It's really only good for adding like a"sample my song" type section to your site. Not really good for a strong mp3 player or anything like that. The potential is there (I've worked with it ALOT) but it still requires a lot of js for binary permissions, ID3 reads, etc ...

Comment: btw what would be the wright site to post such questions ?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I am sure you can find one [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) that would be better suited.  This stack site is more for questions about "how to do something in code" rather than why isn't something being done.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://github.com/NamilD/Nakuma-Player) is a solution for you, just download the zip file and extract it anywhere you want. Then open file "index.html" file using your web browser (Chrome or Firefox). This program still supports Audio/mp3 files only.

[Nakuma Player](https://github.com/NamilD/Nakuma-Player)